# Where I should store SQLite database reference?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm creating simple application that uses JSON format and SQLite database to store parsed information into that. I'm aiming to support both normal devices and tablets, so I'm using Android `Fragment` API.

My problem is that I'm not sure where I should store the reference to my database, at this moment I have main activity that incorporates **two fragments** - list fragment and details fragment (both of them are adjusted for tablets and normal phones).

I need to fill mentioned list with information from database and in future I want to implement additional search function so reference to database must be shared by almost all fragments/activities.

In addition I have special class(`Util`) that stores HTTP object and JSON parser. Is it good idea to add static database reference to that class and create new instance of it in seperate thread (initialization block) ? Or I should consider create it in `MainActivitity` and create getter and setter ? My `MainActivity` implements appropriate interfaces from list fragment so I'd need to cast it.

Comment: I always add an Application instance and a static variable to hold the DB reference.

Comment: you should keep only in one place: your custom content provider